# Keeping Large Database on a separate SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, database, instance, large-files

I'm in the process of migrating some databases to SQL Server 2012 one of the database is a large database in comparison to the rest, it about 64GB and can grow to about 200GB. This database is currently sitting on a separate instance because of its size but it shares the same data drive as the rest. I'm now trying to weigh up whether or not I want to continue keeping this database on a separate instance or put all the databases on one instance. I was wondering if some DBA's out there can advise me on some of the thing I have consider in my choices and decision making

I'm not looking for file grouping solution

Keep two instances separately (Large Databases in Instance1 and Small Databases in Instance2)

Comment: Why is it in a separate instance in the first place? What were the original reasons?

Comment: The only reason I have been given is that its on a separate instance because it was large database but now I'm want to have the databases on a single instance but I want to know what consideration i need to have.